# vsoagent-installer silently failing

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I've been following the steps for installing the vsoagent-installer on linux (Ubuntu 15.4). I've installed it but I have a problem when running it to create agents.

The `vsoagent-installer` command exits without any output and without copying the agent files in the directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog introduces the detailed steps on how to create a vNext build agent on Linux machine. Check http://realalm.com/2015/06/26/creating-a-build-vnext-agent-on-linux/

Some key steps here:

1. Install Node.js and npm on the Linux machine. Use the command: sudo apt-get install nodejs
2. Install the vso-installer. Use the command: sudo npm install vsoagent-installer –g
3. Create a folder and install agent on that folder:
   mkdir linuxagent1
   cd linuxagent1
   vsoagent-installer
4. Type “node agent/vsoagent” to start the configuration.

Have a check whether you take the same steps.

Comment: yes, I used these exact steps, except `vsoagent-installer` command doesn't do anything